# Why does AVD need the Qt library?

Tags: android, qt

I've installed Android Studio 2.0 and I'm trying to create a new AVD with the following specs:

```
Hardware profile is Nexus 5
Marshmallow API 23 and ABI x86_64
```

However, when I tried to start the AVD, I got the following error :

> ERROR:./android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:33:Qt library not found at
>   ${SDK_HOME}/tools/lib64/qt/lib Could not launch
>   '${SDK_HOME}/tools/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64': No such file
>   or directory

Or the following if I used Marshmallow API 23 and ABI x86:

> ERROR:./android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:33:Qt library not found at
>   ${SDK_HOME}/tools/lib64/qt/lib Could not launch
>   '${SDK_HOME}/tools/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386': No such file
>   or directory

My laptop (HP probok 4530s) specs are:

```
Hardware: CORE i5, 6GB ram, no external Graphic card.
OS: CentOS 6.6
```

Comment: try creating one with Google Api's system images

Comment: Could you explain more? sorry because this is my first time

Comment: when you downloaded system image for your emulator there are two types of images 1. x86 either Intel or ARM  and 2. with Google API system images.

Comment: @VivekMishra : I've checked it and it is installed with Google API

Comment: now create your emulator using this image

Comment: @VivekMishra : I meant that the emulators are already created by these images and I got these errors

Comment: you are using linux??

Comment: @VivekMishra : Yes as mentioned in the question Centos 6.6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108895/discussion-between-m-e-and-vivek-mishra).

Comment: I see nothing about Qt in the error message?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld : ????

Comment: Eh, misread. Nevermind... Read it as qemu executable not found.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld : NVM

Comment: Any luck @M_E ?? Me too facing same issue.. Any solution..

Comment: No I didn't found the solution, I changed my OS

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/43093003/969478

Please try running `$SDK/emulator/emulator` instead of `$SDK/tools/emulator`.

Comment: If that is the case, you should mark the question as duplicate instead of posting this answer.